# classification: VFI5 algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, classification

- Do you know anything about the VFI5 algorithm?
- some example?

This algorithm is supossed to clasiffy a data set, based on voting, but I would like to know more about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find more detail about VF15, which is a "a supervised and inductive learning algorithm for inducing classification knowledge from examples," [here](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/tech-reports/1998/BU-CEIS-9802.pdf).